# Flutter : Qr Scan

Tags: flutter, dart

I using package [barcode_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) for my app, but when debut it showing this kind of error. how do i solve it?

[click the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT5L0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pub file support minimum sdk version is 18.
and your minimum sdk version is 16.

as you show in error image.

[image]

so,
upgrade your minimum sdk version for using this library.
'Your Project'/android/app/build.gradle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says
You need to change the **minsdk version to 18** because the library doesn't support lower than version 18.

**You need to change the minsdk version in the Gradle file**

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to change the minsdk version to 18 and use minsdk version : 16

2.And build again and run it